# Get value from pandas series object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a bunch of data files, with columns 'Names', 'Gender', 'Count', one file per one year. I need to concatenate all the files for some period, sum all counts for all unique names and add a new column with amount of consonant. I can't extract string value  from 'Names'. How can I implement that?
Here is my code:

```
import os
import re
import pandas as pd

PATH = ...
def consonants_dynamics (years):
    names_by_year = {}
    for year in years:
        names_by_year[year] = pd.read_csv(PATH+"\\yob{}.txt".format(year), names =['Names', 'Gender', 'Count'])
    names_all = pd.concat(names_by_year, names=['Year', 'Pos'])
    dynamics = names_all.groupby('Names').sum().sort_values(by='Count', ascending=False).unstack('Names')
    dynamics['Consonants'] = dynamics.apply(count_vowels(dynamics.Names), axis = 1)
    return dynamics.head(10)

def count_vowels (name):
    vowels = re.compile('A|E|I|O|U|a|e|i|o|u')
    return len(name) - len (vowels.findall(name))
```

If I run something like

```
a = consonants_dynamics(i for i in range (1900, 2001, 10))
```

I get the following error message

```
<ipython-input-9-942fc155267e> in consonants_dynamcis(years)
...
---> 12     dynamics['Consonants'] = dynamics.apply(count_vowels(dynamics.Names), axis = 1)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Names'
```

I tried various ways but all failed. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after doing unstack you converted dynamics to a series object where you no longer have Names column `dynamics.Names`. I think it should be fixed by removing `.unstack('Names')`

after that use dynamics.index:

`dynamics['Consonants'] = dynamics.reset_index()['Names'].apply(count_vowels)`

Comment: Pity, doesn't help. I removed it and got the similar error message AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Names'

Comment: please provide a sample from the dataframe `names_all.head(10).to_dict()`

Comment: `                  Count
Names 
James 497673
John 486018
Robert 473585
Michael 424833
Mary 394859
William 381327
David 354754
Richard 249947
Joseph 241402
Charles 227669`

Comment: Count<br/>
Names<br/> 
James 497673<br/>
John 486018<br/>
Robert 473585<br/>

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgqmk46v8y1gjgt/DataFrame.png?dl=0) in this way...

Comment: corrected the solution, please use index instead of Names

Comment: @ lsalamo I think I got the problem, but do not know yet how to tackle it.  dynamics.apply(count_vowels(dynamics.index), axis = 1) passes a list to count_vowels, but count_vowels  works with a string arg. The question is how to handle the list in this case.

Comment: updated, a reset index is needed then you can access the needed column

Answer (score 1):

Convert `index` [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) and apply function:

```
print (dynamics)
        Count
Names        
James       2
John        3
Robert     10

def count_vowels (name):
    vowels = re.compile('A|E|I|O|U|a|e|i|o|u')
    return len(name) - len (vowels.findall(name))


dynamics['Consonants'] = dynamics.index.to_series().apply(count_vowels)
```

Solution without function with [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and substract only wovels by [`str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html):

```
pat = 'A|E|I|O|U|a|e|i|o|u'
s = dynamics.index.to_series()
dynamics['Consonants_new'] = s.str.len() - s.str.count(pat)
```

---

```
print (dynamics)
        Count  Consonants_new  Consonants
Names                                    
James       2               3           3
John        3               3           3
Robert     10               4           4
```

EDIT:

Solutions without `to_series` is add `as_index=False` to `groupby` for return `DataFrame`:

```
names_all = pd.DataFrame({
'Names':['James','James','John','John', 'Robert', 'Robert'],
'Count':[10,20,10,30, 80,20]
})

dynamics = names_all.groupby('Names', as_index=False).sum()
                    .sort_values(by='Count', ascending=False)

pat = 'A|E|I|O|U|a|e|i|o|u'
s = dynamics.index.to_series()
dynamics['Consonants'] = dynamics['Names'].str.len() - dynamics['Names'].str.count(pat)

print (dynamics)
    Names  Count  Consonants
2  Robert    100           4
1    John     40           3
0   James     30           3
```